# exception netty ReferenceCountUtil safeRelease

Tags: netty

```
public class EchoServer {

private final int port;

public EchoServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new EchoServer(80).start();
}

public void start() throws InterruptedException {
    EchoServerHandler handler = new EchoServerHandler();
    MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(group)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(handler).addLast(myHandler);
                    }
                });

        ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
    }
}
```

}

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
```

public class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println(msg.refCnt());
}
```

}

this is my code,when server start, cmd->telnet localhost 80
Program Exception
server received: h
1
三月 08, 2018 10:34:04 下午 io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil safeRelease
警告: Failed to release a message: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(freed)
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, increment: 1
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release0(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:100)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:84)

i don't know this why

Comment: Hmm this not makes a lot of sense... Are you sure this is the only thing you do in the handler and this is the only handler ? Also I think your stack trace may not be complete

Comment: yes i am sure  the code is here

Comment: Can you share a full reproducer on GitHub or so ?